# incrementing stack length before returning - why does it work?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Below are some methods I implemented for a stack. I'm having trouble seeing why, in the .pop() function, you can decrement the length before returning the relevant value, and yet have the correct value be returned. why is that? is it something to do with the reference vs the value? Intuitively I would think that if I decremented before the return statement in pop, it would return the value before the one that I wanted, not the correct one.

```
stackMethods.pop = function(){

  if(this.length > 0){
        this.length--; //why does decrementing here still return
//the correct value here:
    return this.storage[this.length];
  }

}

stackMethods.push = function(val){
  this.storage[this.length] = val;
  this.length++;
}

stackMethods.size = function(){
  return this.length;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `var storage=[0,1,2];` has length of 3, but it only has `storage[0]`, `storage[1]` and `storage[2]`, **no** `storage[3]`.

Comment: Its the difference between length and index. Think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last element of an array is at the index `length - 1`, since array indexing starts at 0.

Imagine the case where your object only has one element and then you call pop. The element will be at `this.storage[0]`, but `this.length === 1`. You can either access `this.storage[ this.length - 1 ]` and then decrement `this.length`, or decrement it first like the code you've shown does.

If the array's own `length` property were decremented, that would remove the last element from the array, but the `length` property is not a property of the array since the actual array is in `this.storage` and the property being decremented is `this.length` and not `this.storage.length`.

Comment: +1 great answer! I think the important point here is that `this.storage` and `this` are not referring to (pointing to) the same array.